# Rails Guides example for testing mailers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

The rails guides example code for testing mailers is as follows:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
  tests UserMailer
  test "invite" do
    # Send the email, then test that it got queued
    email = UserMailer.create_invite('me@example.com',
                                     'friend@example.com', Time.now).deliver
    assert !ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.empty?

    # Test the body of the sent email contains what we expect it to
    assert_equal ['me@example.com'], email.from
    assert_equal ['friend@example.com'], email.to
    assert_equal 'You have been invited by me@example.com', email.subject
    assert_equal read_fixture('invite').join, email.body.to_s
  end
end
```

What is the purpose of this line and do I have to add it in my tests? -->
**tests UserMailer**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the [tests method implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/73deb3af23765882f67869afb4eaa8ad74a351d1/actionpack/lib/action_view/test_case.rb#L53)

Here is what `carlosantoniodasilva` says about `tests`

> You can use tests in mailers/controllers/helpers tests to define
>   which  mailer/controller/helper you're testing, in case it cannot be
>   automatically guessed from the  test name. eg, UserMailerTest
>   automatically guesses UserMailer as the test subject, but you can
>   explicitly say that or say it's a different name with the tests
>   method. So having the line there is not entirely wrong, it's just
>   being explicit about what Rails does automatically.

You can read the entire discussion on this very specific topic at [Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13940)

Comment: Are you Indian? :-) Me too :-)